# Why is SELECT creating an uncommitted transaction in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, commit

I have disabled autocommit in SSMS.
I have been playing around with it today and after some bizarre (to me, anyway) behaviour narrowed the use case to the following:

- connect to db
- open a new a query (ctrl n)
- issue a simple SELECT statement eg

  select TOP (5) * from AdventureWorks2017.Person.Person
- close the window

I get the following message in a dialog (dialogue, hmm) box:

```
There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these transactions before closing the window?
```

Being a long-time Oracle user, I was aware there are differences in locking between Oracle and SS, but `select`s causing an outstanding transaction that needs to be committed or rolled back?  Really?  This can't be so, surely. No data has changed. Please could somebody explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're working with the console, it automatically puts your queries into a transaction.  Because you haven't closed the transaction it automatically started when you started running queries of any kind, you still have a transaction open.

This MSDN article talks a bit about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql

Comment: Are you saying that there's an implicit "BEGIN TRANSACTION" prepended to any statement that I execute in the query window? If that's the case, if I say do "select ...." and execute and then another "select...." and execute, do I have two implicit BEGIN TRANSACTIONS?

Comment: Sort of.  A good way to track all this used to be to open up SQL profiler and watch all the events and see what was happening under the hood.

Comment: You can do a Print @@TRANCOUNT before and after your select and see what the value is.  According to the documentation, if trancount > 0 it doesn't create another Begin Trans...but your first statement in your exemple comment will.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your second question buried in there.  As I recall, you won't have two transactions unless you explicitly open up a second one.  You generally have the one per window.  I personally left the autocommit on in SSMS, generally, because rolling back a transaction is fairly easy much of the time and I was more Dev than DBA. Mucking around with live data was for more beardy guys like I now kinda am.

Comment: It's going to take me some time to figure out how to use SQL Profiler but in the meantime what is clear is that a transaction is implicitly started with a SELECT and that transaction needs either committing or rolling back. This is annoying; I have spent a decade with Oracle wherein SELECTs don't need rolling back just because you have autocommit off.  Is there any way to avoid this particular behaviour ie to have autocommit off, and not have SELECT stmts needing to be rolled back?  It is very, very odd to be asked to commit (or not) a session in which all I've done is select stuff from the db

Comment: If you have a query window with your select transactions all in one block you won't notice that the queries are stacking up.  Honestly, SQL Server is significantly more user-friendly (in my experience) than Oracle so you may end up pleasantly surprised with other things where this one irritates you.

Comment: Yes I'm not having a dig at SS, it's just weird to have SELECTs needing to be committed or otherwise. No data has been changed. I'd like to have the same behaviour as Oracle SQLPlus ie autocommit off, select statements not being wrapped in a transaction. Is that possible?  Thanks.

Comment: @JL_SO, what you ask is not possible, which is autocommit for select statements and IMPLICT_TRANSACTIONS ON for data modifications. Note that unlike Oracle, SQL Server allows DDL within transactions so a CREATE will start a transaction with IMPLICT_TRANSACTIONS ON.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. It seems I will just have to get used to this irritating behaviour. More important is that I've found that writes block reads (I'm reasonably certain Tom Kyte said in one of his Oracle tomes that on Oracle writers never block readers and readers never block writers); I will need to create a separate question for that.

Comment: There are multiple concurrency levels.  I believe SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION is closer to what you are used to with Oracle.